# Auto-releasing npm packages through CI using Lerna

Tags: git, npm, continuous-integration, lerna

In my company we're using lerna to manage a repo of javascript libraries. We have about 30 packages and 10 developers working on this. As the team is growing and the number of packages are growing too, we're looking for a simple way to manage how we release new versions of each packages automatically.

We trigger new releases several times a day based on which package changed so our projects can consume the new libraries. We're restricted to trigger releases from our CI only as we don't have the credentials to push to our internal npm repository. So we run `lerna publish --exact --skip-npm` locally to bump each packages which had a change, then we merge the package.json files and run this through the CI which takes care of the publishing part.

This causes issues over time, especially if more than one developer try to release at the same time. Or when the person bumping the versions is not the person who've changed the code and doesn't know if it should be a patch, minor bump etc.

As we're using typescript, one idea we had was to compare the d.ts files from the previous release with the one from the new release to know if something has changed, and decide automatically to bump a patch or a minor.  Major bump would be done manually by developers. Though the d.ts files are not in the git repo so it would be annoying to do something like this.

I'm wondering if someone has experience to manage packages on such a repo? What's your workspace like? How do you take care of releases in a continuous integration environment?

Thanks!